# android simple list view of all sms/mms messages

Tags: java, android, sms

hello all i wish to do is have a non threaded sms app as apposed to the default application.
how would i import the current sms/mms 's on the phone to an array?

Edit:) so how is it that for instance handcent sms imports all of my existing sms messages?

Comment: SMS and MMS are handled by an application, not the operating system. You would need to contact the authors of every SMS/MMS application you wish to support how to access that data in their case. For the Messaging application that is part of the Android open source project, there is no documented and supported means of accessing the saved messages.

Comment: so how is it that for instance handcent sms imports all of my existing sms messages?

Comment: Take a look at this: [How can I read SMS messages from the inbox programmatically in Android?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android