# android accessing sms by time

Tags: android, sms

I am looking into developing an app that would allow you to sort sms by time. Say if you wanted to find all the texts you sent yesterday, etc. Can someone help me out and get me started on how to search through the sms's by time and then maybe show ones that meet the criteria. I have done some developing, just nothing with the sms.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android) should give you all you need.  There are lots of good resources already online for stuff like this - you just have to search for them.

Comment: I want something so basically I set a range of dates/times, click go and display those texts only. Any help on this?