# Can we display Notifications in our activity other than status bar?

Tags: android

I wanted to display latest messages and incoming call alerts in my activity.
Can I override that in my activity inside a list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and you can use the call log. You should familiarize yourself with

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html

and content providers

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

As for SMS, please see this question:

[How can I read SMS messages from the device programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android)