# Retrieve all inbox messages of device in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, message

I am using this code.

```
Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus"); 

SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length]; 

StringBuilder messageText = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {                 
     messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pduArray [i]);              
     messageText.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());          
}
```

But this code is for only intimate when sms is received in a device but my need is to retrieve all inbox messages which is saved in android device  in android how can I do it?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android.

Comment: check this: [Android – Fetch Inbox SMS](http://www.technotalkative.com/?p=1817)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code :

```
   Uri SMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
   String[] projection = new String[]{"_id", "address", "body", "date"};
   Cursor cursor = null;

   try {
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(SMSURI
                , projection
                , null //selection
                , null //selectionArgs
                , null); //sortOrder

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int    id    = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
                String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
                String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Message is >>"+body, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```