# Reading SMS in android, showing wrong count

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to read sms in android. In my manifest file, I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

My Code:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/inbox"), null, null, null,null);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.info1)).setText("Number of messages: " + cursor.getColumnCount());
```

The problem is that I have more than 17 smses in my inbox but the output it gives is

**Number of messages: 17**

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android),  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209507/retreive-all-inbox-meseges-of-device-in-android?lq=1), [this](http://mobdev.olin.edu/mobdevwiki/FrontPage/Tutorials/SMS%20Messaging) and [this](http://pastebin.com/iPt7MLyM). Can someone please tell what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for the *column count*:

```
cursor.getColumnCount()
```

Which is very different from what you want:

```
cursor.getCount()
```

---

`getCount()` returns the number of rows in a Cursor, or in this case the number of messages in your inbox.

`getColumnCount()` returns the number of columns in each row; like id, sender, message, time, etc.  Read the second answer here: [How many database columns associated with a SMS in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4022088/1267661)

Comment: Ohhh got it, columnCount tells me the attrubutes, Count tells me the entries. Isnt it??? Accepting answer after three minutes. sof says that