# How to get text from a sms message?

Tags: android, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I read SMS messages from the inbox programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android)

I want to program my app to read a sms and need to read the number from the message is sent.

But I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was already asked. See here:

[How can I read SMS messages from the device programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android)

For more info please see:

http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android

http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-reading-inbox-sms.html