# Inserting SMS into inbox : android

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider, gsm, smsmanager

> How can I insert on SMS into inbox and set it as unread? I tried using the following code.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", "123456789");
values.put("body", "foo bar");
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

Insertion is working. But I don't know how to set it as unread. Also please tell me what is the type of sms table columns 'status', 'read' and 'seen'? How can I use them? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `values.put("status", SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_UNREAD);`. Status can be anything like read/unread/seen. I have keep it as unread.

Look at [Message status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392472/how-can-i-read-unread-sms-from-inbox-in-android-programatically)

```
values.put("read", true);  // As Read
```

and

```
values.put("read", false); // As Un Read
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried with this. But SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_UNREAD is not available. SmsManager.STATUS_ON_SIM_UNREAD only is available. Anyway its not working.

Comment: SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_UNREAD is available with this package import android.telephony.SmsManager. Import this package

Comment: ok. I was using android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager. Now I changed. Still the status of message added to inbox is read..

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Telephony.Sms.READ as 0/1 (Unread/Read)according to the requirement.

If messageDirection is

INCOMING then contentUri = Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI

OUTGOING = Telephony.Sms.Sent.CONTENT_URI

```
    ContentValues smsValues = new ContentValues();
    smsValues.put(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS, phoneNumber);
    smsValues.put(Telephony.Sms.BODY, smsMessage);
    smsValues.put(Telephony.Sms.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
    smsValues.put(Telephony.Sms.READ, 0);
    return context.getContentResolver().insert(contentUri, smsValues);
```