# Enable to retrieve inbox sms from android phone

Tags: android, sms, inbox

```
ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null,null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cursor.getCount(); j++) {
        String text = cursor.getString(
        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
        Log.d("sms", text);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
} else
    Log.d("no", "not working");
}
```

I also givev permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>` in androidmanifest.xml file it shows no notworking

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read SMS messages from the inbox programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "not working" ? What problems are you facing ?

Comment: .. and have you confirmed there are SMS messages in the inbox? (by default, there won't be anything in the emulator)

Comment: @swayam-just to know wheather it is gong in if or else

Comment: @sameer-yes i insert 2 sms to emulator

Comment: Hey it works:-)i guess this code was nt working coz inbox of emulator contain sms send by itself..when i send sms using another emulator it works...by the way thanks to all f u