# How do you get all the sms(inbox) from android device?

Tags: android, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I read SMS messages from the inbox programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android)

I want get all the inbox sms from an android device. How do I do that?

Comment: see [this](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2011/10/listen-sms-mms-programmatically-android.html) may help you

Answer (score 7):

You can get inbox messages from following method.

```
public List<String> getSMS(){
     List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
               String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
               String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
              sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);  

          }
        return sms;

    }
```