# Extract SMS from Android

Tags: java, android, database, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I read SMS messages from the inbox programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android)

I'm trying to build a program that extracts SMS from android devices through a java program. Does anyone know an API that does this?

I'm aware the SMS (the backups anyway) are stored in a database so I was hoping to find this database on the phone, extract it and then load it into a database.

Comment: Check into the various android "backup" programs - they can back up the sms archives.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following link.

http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Manas provided a good link.

Here is another one that I used.

<strike>http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/</strike>
  is broken => try [via archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130404225329/http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling)

I think you are referring to reading the database. If so,then this question is a repost, see here:

[How can I read SMS messages from the device programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for links. Just want to write a desktop java application that'll extract SMS from android and print them to a relational database. I'm expecting some sort of encryption is place.