# How to read last 3 sms from inbox in Android?

Tags: android, sms, inbox

I used this code

```
    String msgData = "";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    do{

       for(int idx=0;idx<cursor.getColumnCount();idx++)
       {
           msgData += " " + cursor.getColumnName(idx) + ":" + cursor.getString(idx);
       }
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

..and it works, but it returns more data than I want.

How to read 3 last sms (only msg and sender)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply sort the results by date and use the limit clause:

```
getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, new String[] {body, address}, 
    null, null, "date desc limit 3");
```

Comment: how to read only this:

    address:+48505073421
    body:text message

Comment: Use `String string = "address: " + cursor.getString(1) + "  body: " + cursor.getString(0);`

Comment: Please read through [Cursor's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html), you'll find `moveToPosition()` will help you do this.