# I want to create an inbox to retrieve all sms from the custom inbox and display in my app? I dont understand from where to start coding this?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a sms application in android. I'm done with sending and receiving sms . I want to create an inbox to retrieve all sms from the custom inbox and display in my app? I dont understand from where to start coding this? 
I have to continue with creating a lock for the application and an auto responder.
Can someone pls help me about how to create an inbox and retrieve all sms from the default app?

Comment: Welcome to SO. We will not give out *free* code to people who do not first attempt a solution themselves. There are multiple tutorials available... Just use the mystical *Google*.

Comment: Thanks :) But i am not asking for the code. I am asking for an idea :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read SMS messages from the inbox programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this link.It also has encryption decryption of messages.
http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android