# Conversation between two user in android sms

Tags: android, sms

I want to view the conversation between two user in android sms . I am trying to make a sms project in which user will find the sender number in inbox  in a list . And then when he clicks a particular list item he will find the conversation between him and the sender . But now i am in a fix how to do that ,i have searched a lot in the google but can't find the appropriate solution .

Suppose , i send a message "hello" to x. x sends me message "hi". then he send me "what are you doing?" . i send him "nothing" . I want to view this conversation like in this way in my android sms inbox===

```
 me: hello 
 hi:x
 what are you doing?:x
 me: n8ing
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android

Comment: I would recommend to specify what is exactly the problem. What did you try?

Comment: No i am not trying to read the sms from the inbox only. I have already done that. But i want to view the conversation between a particular sender and me. I have tried using the conversation database but can't find the message. i have edited my question have a look.