# Pull messages to android app

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions

does anyone knows how do I pull SMS messages to an app? (SMS or WhatsApp to be exact)
I couldnt found the right permission on google... =\

Comment: Google is your friend! Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get the SMS with the READ_SMS permission and using the code detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/848728/1069068).

WhatsApp is a third party app, and they do not offer any API, Service or Content Provider to retrieve their messages. You cannot do this.