# Where is the SMS Database in Eclipse emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm developing an app that reads the SMS inbox but I want to look at the details of the SQL database (as an administrator) that contains all the SMS messages. I'm using Eclipse to develop the app and all works in the app but where do I find the database? and what would be a good way of accessing it? Using Windows 8 as my development platform

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read SMS messages from the inbox programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: @his - no, it is not a duplicate.  That question uses the content resolver mechanism, while this question seeks to directly access the database (something that could only be done on an emulator or unsecured/rooted device).

Answer (score 0):

If your using emulator of API-10 you can find sms database in /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db you can browse it using file explorer tool of android.Save it to your location and browse it by sqlite database browser.Database contains many tables sms,thread,mms,etc.
If you want to access by programatically you can use content provider of sms (content://sms/inbox).