# Number of unread or read SMS in Google Hangouts is always 0

Tags: java, android, sms, telephony, google-hangouts

I am trying to find the number of unread SMS messages I have received via Google Hangouts.I tried this answer ([Using new Telephony content provider to read SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856338/using-new-telephony-content-provider-to-read-sms)), and modified the code to count unread messages. It returns 0 every time. If I try to get the read count, by switching `"read = 0"` to `"read = 1"`, the count is still 0.

I realize this means I have an empty SMS inbox in Hangouts, but in reality I do not. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

When I switch my default SMS app to Messenger, it gets the unread count without a problem.

Finally, this is the code I'm using:

```
 private int getUnreadMessageCount() {
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI, null, "read = 0", null, null);
        int unreadCount = c.getCount();
        c.close();
        return unreadCount;
    }
```

Any help is truly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your link is from 2010, I am not sure this is still possible now. Also, just to be sure, [did you request the permission to read SMS to the user](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html) (API > 23) ?

Comment: I did, yes, (edited the question to include that now). Do you how to do this in 2017?

Comment: `READ_SMS` is a `dangerous permission` now, you will need to [ask for the permission at *runtime*](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). As for listing SMS _the 2017 way_, you will have to wait for someone else to answer :). But first try with this permission system, or manually grant the permission on the app settings.

Comment: That's still how you query the SMS Provider. If your inbox is empty, but Hangouts is showing messages, then I suspect your problem is Hangouts. It does something funky with messaging all around when it's the default. I don't use it, so I've never had a chance to pin down exactly what it does. To test, you might temporarily set your default to a different SMS app - the basic Messenger, if you have it - send yourself some texts, and do your query again. I'd also suggest querying the base `content://sms` URI, with a null selection, to see if you've got any kind of messages there at all.

Comment: Yep, so it seems to get the count when Messenger is the default. No such luck for Hangouts.

Comment: @MikiP did you find a solution for this? Running into the same thing now.

Comment: @TravisChambers  I did not. I ended up using Messenger instead. I think it's the way Google wants devs to go.