# Android SMS path

Tags: android, path, sms

I can't find the path of SMS database files in android os. where is the right path for SMS database files?

I already tried these values and these values are not right:

```
/data/data/com.jb.gosms/databases/gommssms.db
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to access the file directly? Android supplies a provider for the messaging database.

Comment: Which provider and how can i use it?

Comment: use  Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan this code returns /

Comment: Or tell me what you need from the message ???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can Find your Answer from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android)

By this way you can read all the message and according to your requirement manage it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mokee rom this is the location:- data/data/com.android.messaging/databases/bugle_db Copy it using some root file browser(ES explorer/Amaze file manager) and rename it to bugle_db.db