# Reading a text message by third party application

Tags: android, google-maps

I am develpoing an application which is used to point to a location on the map....location co ordinates are got by a message.Can i parse that message in my app(third party) as that message contains latitude and longitude of the location that needs to be shown on the map

Comment: Message like e-mail or SMS or ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android take a look here