# Select specific sms thread in android and get it in android app

Tags: android, sms

I want to create an app that once you click on a button in the main page you will see all the SMS threads and be able to choose one. once you choose one I want to take all its messages and do something with it and then show the result on the screen.
Is there some way to start the regular SMS app from my app and then it will send it to my app or should I list all the SMS threads in another activity and then allow to choose a thread?

If only the latter option is valid, should I use the SmsManager?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with an app with 3 activities: main, allSms and secificSms.
When you press on a button in the main activity it opens the allSms activity.
This activity is showing all the SMS messages in the inbox using code from here: [How can I read SMS messages from the device programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android)
When you press on a specific message in this activity we start the specificSms activity with the thread Id and show all the messages with this thread Id.