# How to read the SMS using shell commands In Rooted android Device?

Tags: java, android, shell

Hi i am developing application to read SMS using shell Commands (Only for Rooted Device )

Example Code

> - Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"mkdir /sdcard/testdir\"").waitFor(); --> To create directory
> - Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");   --> Super User Permission
> - Runtime.getRuntime().exec("??");     --What is the Command To Read SMS

Comment: An answer to this question would be helpful for people who try to write a malicious app that steals data from users. In the hope that this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You don't need root permissions to read SMS, [there is an official API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android) for that. The only "drawback" of using it is that your users will be notified that you're reading their messages. If you still need an answer, please elaborate on why you need it.

Comment: Yes , i need answer for this question because i am creating application which can steal SMS from device ... this is the requirement  .... Please note : this application is for schools students ... so their parents can track their activities ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to read any value from content resolver you can access it via its uri. like

```
adb shell content query --uri content://sms --projection _id,address,body,read,date,type
```

pass this command in exec, you will get the result like

> Row: 0 _id=2, address=5554, body=Testing, read=1, date=1469533087074,
>   type=2
>
> Row: 1 _id=1, address=5554, body=Hi, read=1,
>   date=1469533011944, type=2

you can get specific sms using specific uri

```
content://sms/inbox 
content://sms/sent
```

it will helpful to you.

**Update**

you can run it from java code like

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","content query --uri content://sms --projection _id,address,body,read,date,type"});
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply i will check and let u know

Comment: @VickySmart if the answer is helpful to you, accept it as correct answer so that other people can get it easily. :)

Comment: Yes Definitely this will be really help full i need more info regarding this can u help me ??  ...

Comment: Someone minus voted this question ... i don't know why