# Unable to read all SMS from inbox on Specific Devices (MI devices)

Tags: android

My inbox contain Approx. 2032 sms but this query return me only 206 sms. Total sms: 7024

```
 Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
               String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
               String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
              sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);  

          }
        return sms;
```

Comment: That query will only return SMS. Are you certain the missing messages are actually SMS? Not MMS, RCS, etc.?

Comment: yes,  all are sms. no mms,rsc etc

Comment: How are you determining that?

Comment: same query working fine on other phones

Comment: i tested manually on MI Note 3 phone. and check inbox manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read SMS messages from the device programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-device-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: i had already done that. but issue is my MI phone contains 2032 sms in inbox when i try to fetch all sms it return me only 206 sms.

Comment: Issue is solved by using this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45032638/how-to-get-permission-for-read-service-sms-in-miui-8-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

From API 19 onwards you can make use of the Telephony Class for that; Since hardcored values won't retrieve messages in every devices because the content provider Uri changes from devices and manufacturers.

```
public void getAllSms(Context context) {

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = cr.query(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int totalSMS = 0;
    if (c != null) {
        totalSMS = c.getCount();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < totalSMS; j++) {
                String smsDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.DATE));
                String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS));
                String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.BODY));
                Date dateFormat = new Date(Long.valueOf(smsDate));
                String type = null;
                switch (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.TYPE)))) {
                    case Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX:
                        type = "inbox";
                        break;
                    case Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT:
                        type = "sent";
                        break;
                    case Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX:
                        type = "outbox";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                if (type != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Message present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No message to show!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: please attach debugger and look any of the case is getting triggered

Comment: only 206 sms fetched not all and issue is on only on specific MI devices

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: see buddy: "content://sms" is also working but the issue is my phone has 2032 total sms but when i tried to fetch all sms i able to fetch only 206 sms

Comment: Try to fetch sms in worker thread.

May be blocking issue by system.

Comment: I dig more into it and come to know that I am able to read all messages except promotional, like, messages from banks, service providers etc.. which clubbed into notifications in MI. Any way to read them as well?

Comment: @MohitPandey Did you find any solution?

Comment: i think the code which i had posted works for all the general SMS, but won't work on promotional messages, service provider messages, becuase Mi is considering them as notifications instead of SMS messages.so i suggest you to try for notification history to get that messages too.