# How to get Permission for read “Service SMS” in MIUI 8+ (programmatically)

Tags: android, permissions, sms

How to check read service SMS permission is off/on for My application of MI phone. I am building an application where I need to read SMS from phone. Now for MI phone some SMS goes to Notification message and to read them I need a service sms permission on. Below is the screenshot of it.

[image]

Comment: just follow the link [stackoverflowlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45032638/how-to-get-permission-for-read-service-sms-in-miui-8-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

It will take all necessary permission if you just call  `requestSmsPermission()` before your sms read code

```
private void requestSmsPermission() {
    String permission = Manifest.permission.READ_SMS;
    int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        String[] permission_list = new String[1];
        permission_list[0] = permission;
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {                                      
            Toast.makeText(AccountClass.this,"permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AccountClass.this,"permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment . Please up vote it if you like now