# How to set "android.intent.action.MAIN" for 2 or more java class

Tags: android

How to set `android.intent.action.MAIN` for 2 or more Java classes?
How to set two or more Java class Run same time using the `MAIN` action?

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I try this, but first main action class only worked.
How can I run two class same time using in Android studio?

Comment: why would you need that, you can always fork a thread to to perform asynchronous operations. can you explain requirement ?

Comment: how can I get location using sms in my application..sms give latitude and longitude..how can i get location in my map view using the msg.

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-device-programmatically-in-android

Comment: I try to pass value using Intent.but StartActivity() method not find.how can i fix it?I cant Extends the class.because it allready extend AppCompatActivity.

Comment: post code with explanation what you are trying to achieve.