# How to get information when an SMS is send?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I would like to have the information when a user receives/sends an SMS. I have created a SmsWatcher class for this purpose.

```
using AeroMobile.Utility.Helper;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Provider;

[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED", "android.intent.action.SENDTO", "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class SmsWatcher : BroadcastReceiver
{

public override async void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.Action != null)
    {
        if (intent.Action.Equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SmsReceivedAction))
        {
            var msgs = Telephony.Sms.Intents.GetMessagesFromIntent(intent);
            foreach (var msg in msgs)
            {
                //incoming message
            }
        }
        if (intent.Action.Equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SmsDeliverAction))
        {
            var msgs = Telephony.Sms.Intents.GetMessagesFromIntent(intent);
            foreach (var msg in msgs)
            {
                //outgoing message
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

and I register this broadcast service in the MainActivity like below:

```
    //starting SMS watcher service
    var smsWatcherIntent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(SmsWatcher));
    SendBroadcast(smsWatcherIntent);
```

Above code perfectly works for the incoming messages but not for outgoing messages. Can you please help me to get information when a user sends SMS like the information I am getting for incoming messages?

Comment: Don't you need to use android.intent.action.SENDTO ?

Comment: @Jon, thanks and yes, I used that too. Still, it is not working. The question was updated too.

Comment: SmsDeliverAction is not the right Intent. (taken from the documentation): SMS_DELIVER_ACTION
Broadcast Action: A new text-based SMS message has been received by the device.

Comment: @Jon  I was having a line break on the if condition to look at the Intent.Action. An OnReceive method is not even triggered when I send an SMS. :-(

Comment: I don't think there is a way to intercept outgoing SMS messages, but I could be wrong. You could try this other Stack post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-device-programmatically-in-android

Comment: You cannot use SMS_DELIVER_ACTION, it doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: Yes. Hence I am looking for a solution.

Comment: Look above, I posted another stack question where the user wants to read the SMS messages on the device. You'll need to develop an algorithm to periodically check these and use a timestamp or ID to filter the new ones.

Comment: I can see the answer focusing mostly on the incoming messages. I could do that through SmsReceivedAction Intent. Anyway, I will follow the idea and create periodic service for that. Thanks for your help, anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41463479/3682161)

It seems it is NOT that easy to read outgoing messages from the `BroadcastReceiver`. Hence, the best way to read SMS is from the Android Database through Cursor.

Below is the code snippet for `Xamarin.Android`:

```
    private async Task CheckAndUpdateSms(Context context)
    {
        string lastReadTimeMilliseconds = Application.Current.Properties["LastSmsReadMilliseconds"].ToString();
        ICursor cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(Telephony.Sms.ContentUri, null, "date > ?", new string[] { lastReadTimeMilliseconds }, null);

        if (cursor != null)
        {
            int totalSMS = cursor.Count;
            if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
            {
                double maxReceivedTimeMilliseconds = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < totalSMS; j++)
                {
                    double smsReceivedTimeMilliseconds = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.Date)).ToProperDouble();
                    string smsReceivedNumber = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.Address));
                    int smsType = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.Type)).ToProperInt();

                    //you can process this SMS here

                    if (maxReceivedTimeMilliseconds < smsReceivedTimeMilliseconds) maxReceivedTimeMilliseconds = smsReceivedTimeMilliseconds;
                    cursor.MoveToNext();
                }

                //store the last message read date/time stamp to the application property so that the next time, we can read SMS processed after this date and time stamp. 
                if (totalSMS > 0)
                {
                    Application.Current.Properties["LastSmsReadMilliseconds"] = maxReceivedTimeMilliseconds.ToProperString();
                }
            }
            cursor.Close();
        }
    }
```