# How to read my own sent sms in the "sms content provider" for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sms

Hi everyone I've found this thread relating on how to retrieve sms data in my phone:

[How can I read SMS messages from the device programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-device-programmatically-in-android)

I did follow what they show as answer, I can now read all the sms I've received but my problem is that i cannot see my own replies to thoses sms.

Can anyone provide a way to see my own text sms in the conversations?

For info my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView rv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String myDate = "2021/06/07 00:10:45";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = sdf.parse(myDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long millis = date.getTime();
        int REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
        }


        Log.i("debug", "intro");
        // Create Inbox box URI
        Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

// List required columns
        String[] reqCols = new String[]{"_id", "date", "body"};

// Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content Provider
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

// Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
        Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, "date>="+String.valueOf(millis), null, null);
      DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c); 
}
```

Comment: up, I only have 14 views in one day this is strange

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to fix this, we can simply use this URI query to see the sent messages:

```
Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
```

Or if we want to see both sent and received we can use:

```
Uri.parse("content://sms");
```