# Is it possible to Import contact from messages using intent from an android device programmatically?

Tags: java, android, message, contacts

Is it possible to import a contact with the default UI(for messaging app) and retrieve its information and process it in the app, in same manner mentioned for Phonebook in below example?
For ex. When we import contacts from phonebook using intent, it opens the Default phonebook UI of the device and we can select a contact to import in our application, I want to achieve the same for importing contact from Messages.
I found a way for importing messages list but I want to select only one message and get its details.

Answer (score -1):

Function to get SMS

```
public List<Sms> getAllSms() {
    List<Sms> lstSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
    Sms objSms = new Sms();
    Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentResolver cr = mActivity.getContentResolver();

    Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
    mActivity.startManagingCursor(c);
    int totalSMS = c.getCount();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {

            objSms = new Sms();
            objSms.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
            objSms.setAddress(c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
            objSms.setMsg(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
            objSms.setReadState(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read")));
            objSms.setTime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).contains("1")) {
                objSms.setFolderName("inbox");
            } else {
                objSms.setFolderName("sent");
            }

            lstSms.add(objSms);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    // else {
    // throw new RuntimeException("You have no SMS");
    // }
    c.close();

    return lstSms;
}
```

Sms class is below:

```
public class Sms{
private String _id;
private String _address;
private String _msg;
private String _readState; //"0" for have not read sms and "1" for have read sms
private String _time;
private String _folderName;

public String getId(){
return _id;
}
public String getAddress(){
return _address;
}
public String getMsg(){
return _msg;
}
public String getReadState(){
return _readState;
}
public String getTime(){
return _time;
}
public String getFolderName(){
return _folderName;
}


public void setId(String id){
_id = id;
}
public void setAddress(String address){
_address = address;
}
public void setMsg(String msg){
_msg = msg;
}
public void setReadState(String readState){
_readState = readState;
}
public void setTime(String time){
_time = time;
}
public void setFolderName(String folderName){
_folderName = folderName;
}

}
```

Don't forget to define permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Comment: Refer this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-device-programmatically-in-android

Comment: @Siddharth Jain Thanks for answering, to show these SMS I'll have to create a layout in my app, I want to use the default UI of native SMS App and select one contact from there, please let me know if that is possible.