# Apple/ Android app policy related to phone call and sms

Tags: android, ios

We planning to develop an app for Bussiness platform,
there is 2 features that we consider if it's allow to have in app

1. Show Customer information in incoming call only customer exists in app DB (create by User and not collecting for any other purposes)
2. Read sms message from Bank in white list (create by User) to progress automatically payment process

anyone have experience on this please help me thank

Comment: It is better to split questions like this into two separate questions, one for each platform. On iOS you can create a callkit directory extension. This allows your app to share a list of numbers and names with iOS to be displayed on incoming calls. Your app cannot have access to incoming call details directly. There is no way to access incoming text messages

Comment: that's mean very few information can be show to User when incoming call appear?

Comment: Correct.  You can provide a name that will be displayed along with the information that the name came from your app

Answer (score 0):

According to Android platform:

1. You can read contacts from phone db, but you'll need special permission (permission.READ_CONTACTS) using Content Provider. You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics).
2. Same for SMS. You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-device-programmatically-in-android).

Comment: maybe you misunderstand my point is show my-own infomation in app instead of using phone contact when incoming call appear